# how to set cookie and use context in the nest middleware

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I use nestjs recently. and i write a auth user middleware, i want set cookie and set user info to the context. but req.cookie() dont exist,
req.context type error

node 8.9
nest latest

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthUserMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {

  }
  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    if (!req.context) {
      req.context = {};
    }
    const uid = req.cookies.uid;
    const user = await this.userService.refreshUser(uid);
    req.cookies("uid", user.uid, {
      httpOnly: false,
      domain: config.domain,
      path: "/"
    });
    req.context.user = user;
    next();
  }
}
```

[image]